# In GIMP 2.8 how in the world to you edit a path?

Tags: path, gimp

As a very experienced Coreldraw user, in Corel there is something called a Pick Tool that let's you activate an object, like making a path you've previously created active so you can edit it.

There appears to be no such functionality in GIMP 2.8.  I created a path using the Lasso tool.  I then did some other operations (adding layers, etc.), and then I tried to return to the path I had created using that Lasso tool.  No luck!  How the heck does one edit a previously entered path in GIMP?

Thanks very much from a frustrated GIMP learner!

Ed in Columbus, OH

Comment: CorelDraw is a vector-based drawing program, where as Gimp is for editing photos (basically), and so the lasso is simply a selection tool.  If you want something similar to CorelDraw you should be using [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/), not Gimp (IMO anyway).  Doing that may remove some of your frustration as the concepts will match better. :)

Answer (score 1):

The lasso tool does not create paths, it creates a selection. The editable outline - well, its last segment - is just available temporarily, unfortunately.

Paths are created by the path tool, and the same tool is used to edit them as well.

You can create paths from selections, and selections from paths, so

1. Lasso
2. Select -> To Path
3. Edit the Path
4. Select -> From Path (if the result is supposed to be a selection)

might be a viable approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking of a path that's gone awry, you used to be able to remove the anchors via Shift Z. Now that removes all the Anchors! Now if you want to remove individual anchors you go to Edit then "remove anchor"